# Is the cache field 'expired_date' no longer used?

Tags: database, cache

After inspecting some cache entries in the civicrm_cache table I've come across the field called 'expired_date' which is set to NULL in all cases.

The only reference to the field I can find anywhere in the codebase is in the schema file. So it looks like this is an old field definition that is no longer used and can be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same reaction when I saw that field -- it doesn't appear to be used.

In fact, I don't think it was ever used. Grepping some of the older releases (http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/branches/v2.0, http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/branches/v2.2), the field appears as part of the 2.1 schema upgrade; however, even then it's not used in any logic.

My suspicion is that the field is more aspirational. (Theory: One person designed the cache layer and included `expired_date` in the schema because it's standard in caching systems; then another person implemented the cache logic but ignored that part of the design.)

I wish the cache supported expiration/TTL, so I'm not anxious to remove the field. It would be even better if someone finished TTL support.

Comment: OK, I shalln't create an issue to remove it. I wouldn't want to hurt CiviCRM's feelings by removing its aspirations ;]

Comment: I think we should make CiviCRM meet its aspirations!